# How can I navigate to a new page, that will have Shell flyout menu?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I need to navigate to a page, that will have shell flyout menu, but I don't need it present as item in menu.

I have tried routing pages

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute("cart", typeof(Cart));
```

and then use

```cs
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///cart");
```

But it throws an error, telling me about the only page in stack.
Microsoft documentation doesn't help.

> Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: cart/

When I tried

```c
Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Cart()));
```

It worked, but topbar was default color and menu button wasn't there.
Also, I have tried to push Cart as a new page, without `new NavigationPage()`, topbar has no changes, but menubutton works as BackButton, even though I set a Behaviour

```xml
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IconOverride="back.png"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using **`Shell.Current.GoToAsync`** will just push another page in your navigation stack,

If you want to navigate to another navigation page using shell, you can just create another Shell File, ex. `AppShell.xaml`(default for shell) and just change your **MainPage** by

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NewAppShell();
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked in my case:

```
// without parameter
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//cart");
// or with parameter
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//cart?item=12345");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

Your path `///cart` is invalid . Global routes currently can't be the only page on the navigation stack. Therefore, absolute routing to global routes is unsupported.

**Solution:**

Navigation can also be performed by specifying a valid relative URI as an argument to the GoToAsync method. The routing system will attempt to match the URI to a ShellContent object. Therefore, if all the routes in an application are unique, navigation can be performed by only specifying the unique route name as a relative URI:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("cart");
```

Comment: This pushes a page, but menubutton works as backbutton, but I need the page to also have a flyout menu

Comment: You should put the content page in `FlyoutItem` . Or you can set the Cart as Master detail page .

Comment: Setting Cart as Master Detail ruins the whole purpose of using Shell. I am making project with complex navigation, so I shose Shell to simplify development

Comment: You can customize the TitleView of the content page .

Comment: I did, same behaviour with menu

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar